# On the steady states for $\frac{dn}{dt}=n(n-a)(1-n)-fn$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, biology, steady-state

I have a question in my homework that asks for me to find the steady states of $$\frac{dn}{dt}=n(n-a)(1-n)-fn$$ where $a<1$.

I already showed in a previous part of the question that there exist two nontrivial steady states if and only if $$f<\frac{(1-a)^2}{4}$$

Graphing $y=(n-a)(1-n)$ and $y=f$, the graph crosses the n-axis (x-axis) at $n=a$ and $n=1$. And we know that $n=0$ is another steady state. However, when plugging $n=1$ and $n=a$ into $\frac{dn}{dt}$ you do not get zero.

The inequality of $f$ is greatly throwing me off in finding the steady states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a biological model, I will assume the initial condition satisfies $n(0) \ge 0$.  Likewise, I will restrict myself to solutions where $n(t) \ge 0$ for all $t$. For ease of notation, write $f^*=(1-a)^2/4$, the value you have identified in your question.

A steady state occurs only when $dn/dt=0$.  That means that $n=0$ or
$$
(n-a)(1-n)=f.
$$
So the trivial steady state $n(t)=0$ for all $t$ will always exist.

The left side of the equation above is a quadratic expression in $n$, as you have noted.  Since $a < 1$ That expression is positive for $a < n < 1$.  It has a maximum at $n = (1+a)/2$.  This maximum value is $f^*$, as you have calculated.

If $f >f^*$, then $dn/dt < 0$ for all $n$, and the population will die out, no matter what the initial condition is.

If $f=f^*$, then $dn/dt = 0$ only when $n = (1+a)/2$.  Thus if $n(0) > (1+a)/2$, the population will shrink to the unique steady state.  And and if $n(0) < (1+a)/2$, the population will die out.  If $n(0)=(1+a)/2$, then any negative perturbation will wipe out the population.  Positive perturbations will result in a return to steady state.

If $ -a \le f < f^*$ and $f$, then there are two steady states with $ n > 0$.  These occur where the parabola described by the above equation intersects the horizontal line with intercept $f$.  Call these two steady states $n_1 < n_2$.  The steady state at $n_1$ is not stable.  If the initial condition $n(0) < n_1$, then the population dies off, and if $n(0) > n_1$, the population will grow to $n2_2$  That steady state is stable.

Finally, if $ f < -a$, then there's only one steady state.  This is the one where the the parabola intersects horizontal line with intercept $f$ and $n > 0$.  It is stable.  Even the trivial steady state is unstable because any positive perturbation will result in a population explosion.

Comment: Than you for your answer. Could you further explain why the steady states have to be between $a$ and $(1+a)/2$ and between $(1+a)/2$ and $1$? I am not seeing this graphically and am having a hard time understanding it

Comment: Because the quadratic form has roots at a and at 1.  The maximum occurs at the midpoint.

Comment: Please replace "That means that $(n-a)(1-n)=f$" by "That means that $n=0$ or that $(n-a)(1-n)=f$".

Comment: "I assumed $f>0$ because most biological models don't make sense with negative populations in steady state." Sorry but the present model makes perfect sense when $f<0$ since every initial condition $n(0)\geqslant0$ yields $n(t)\geqslant0$ for every $t$. **This** is the biological condition you might have in mind. The fact that some fixed points are in $(-\infty,0)$ is irrelevant, actually the function itself on $(-\infty,0)$ is irrelevant since the solutions starting from $[0,+\infty$) do not "see" it.

Comment: Did, your points are well taken.  Are you satisfied with my amended answer?

Comment: Much more sensible now, yes. Of course, a figure would help tremendously...